# How to insert data into a Many to Many table using prisma

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

> My models

```
model Company {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String @unique
  links Links[]
}


model Survey {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String @db.VarChar(200)
  description String? @db.VarChar(500)
  links Links[]
}

model Links {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  company Company @relation(fields:[companyId], references:[id])
  companyId Int
  survey Survey @relation(fields:[surveyId], references:[id])
  surveyId Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}
```

> ⚡ Request

```
routes.post('/links', async (req, res) => {
  const { companyId, surveyId } = req.body
      const result = await prisma.links.create({
        data: {
          companyId,
          surveyId
        }
      })

      res.json(result)
})
```

> Error

```
clientVersion: "3.12.0"
code: "P2002"
meta: {target: "Links_companyId_key"}
target: "Links_companyId_key"
```

I don't understand exactly what is going on.

Is it a model problem?
Is it a problem inserting?

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: This error code means unique constraint failed as per error reference: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference#p2002

Comment: @NurulSundarani What do I have to do to fix this error?